# IntersectionObserver is not defined Vue 3 ssr

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering

Please help! Why this method works in normal build and in ssr does not work.

error: IntersectionObserver is not defined

```
const animatedScrollObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
  (entries, animatedScrollObserver) => {

    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.classList.add('enter');
        animatedScrollObserver.unobserve(entry.target);
      }
    });
  }
);
export default boot(async ({ app }) => {
  app.directive('scrollanimation', {
    beforeMount(el) {
      el.classList.add('before-enter');
      animatedScrollObserver.observe(el);

    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`IntersectionObserver` is client-side API and should be only used in parts that are evaluated in a browser.

There are no reasons for `animatedScrollObserver`  to be defined in module scope, it's not used anywhere but `beforeMounted`. `const animatedScrollObserver = ...` needs to be placed inside `beforeMounted`, as it's client-only lifecycle hook that isn't called on server side.